# Xamarin visual studio not opening .axml file in android project

Tags: c#

When I try to open the layout.axml in visual studio (Xamarin). Please see the screen shot of when I try to update the Android SDK.
I am using visual studio not xamarin studio windows 10 anniversary addition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Close all programs that use this file.
And be more attentive. Alert window told you reason and solution.
P.S.(offtop) I see that you installed your android sdk in program files, don't do that, use simple paths as "c:\android", because some packets wouldn't work properly if path contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

close your visual studio.

go to your android sdk folder. for example ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\

open temp folder. you will see something like this : tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip / tools_r25.2.2-windows.zip.

Extract the latest version to your android sdk folder e.g; C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. It will replace all the files inside tools folder.

open your visual studio and try load back the axml.